# how can I resolve try-catch issue within for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, exception, try-catch

My code is almost finished. It's a guessing number game. The final piece is implementing the try-catch function so that the program catches invalid inputs like a number > 50 or typing in letters or any symbol.

Here's the code:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        //number generator
        int number = 1 + (int)(50 * Math.random());

        int i, guess;
        int g = 50;


        for (i = 0; i < g; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 to 50!");

                guess = s.nextInt();


                if (guess == number) {
                    System.out.println("You got it in " + i + " tries.");
                    System.out.println("The number was: " + number);
                    break;
                } else if (guess < number) {
                    System.out.println("Too low. Try Again.");
                } else if (guess > number) {
                    System.out.println("Too high. Try Again.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Oops you entered an invalid input. Try Again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens at the moment is that when I input letters, it continuously prints the "oops" sentence. when I input a number higher than 50, it just tells that the number is higher.

Comment: Break the loop when `for loop` catch the exception.

Comment: Either put a `break;` next to the `System.out.println` or rethrow the exception.

Comment: putting a break; stops the program. tried the rethrow by adding "throw e;" after the println but it just made an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's not talk about clean code, I simply want to correct your catch clause.

The main problem is, that the Scanner doesn't consume the `.nextInt()` if it's an invalid input.

That means after catching your exception the line is still there and will automatically be read again in your next iteration. Theoretically this would end in an infinite loop, but due to your structure your loop is limited by `int g = 50;`.

The only (and not that clean) solution I know is, to let the scanner simply consume the next line with `.nextLine()` or `.next()`.

The solution that [@Chaosfire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17795888/chaosfire) mentioned is way better.

`guess = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());`

You will first read the line, no matter what its content is. Afterwards you try to parse the content to an Integer. In case the input is invalid the method will throw a `NumberFormatException`, that you catch in your catch clause.

### Suggestion for loop

```
for(i = 0; i < g; i++) {
  System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 to 50!");
  try {
    guess = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());

    if((guess < 1) || (guess > 50)) {
      throw new Exception("Integer is not in Range between 1 and 50");
    }
    if(guess == number) {
      System.out.println("You got it in " + i + " tries.");
      System.out.println("The number was: " + number);
      break;
    }
    else if(guess < number) {
      System.out.println("Too low. Try Again.");
    }
    else if(guess > number) {
      System.out.println("Too high. Try Again.");
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    i--;
    System.out.println("Oops you entered an invalid input: " + e.getMessage() + "\nTry Again.");
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. I'll try your solution right now.

Comment: Actually the cleanest solution is to replace `guess = s.nextInt();` with `guess = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());` - directly consuming and parsing the input. Reassigning new value to the scanner is, well..., not a good idea. Other than that, good explanation on what's causing the problem.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is a better way and then catch the `NumberFormatException` the parser would throw.

Comment: Ok. The code is working properly. inputting anything other than numbers will print the "oops" message and go back to the loop. I still need to fix 2 things:

Display a message when a user inputs a value greater than 50
and the invalid input will not be counted as the number of tries

Comment: I edited the solution due to @Chaosfire s recommendation and your required changes.

To explain it you first have to check if the value is in your range in another if-condition.

In your catch clause you have to decrease your count variable by one to ignore the invalid try.

Comment: So far, the code is now working as it should be. Thank you @luis_ske and to Chaosfire